# Apify with puppeteer in Docker root user problem

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer, chromium, apify

I'm trying to use Apify in Docker container, but a strange error occurs

Here's Dockerfile:

```
FROM apify/actor-node-chrome

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

USER root

RUN ./setup.sh
```

here's setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
npm run run
```

npm run run executes node index.js command
Here's index.js

```
const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
    requestQueue,
    handlePageFunction: async ({ ... }) => {
        ...
    },
    launchPuppeteerOptions:{
        headless: true
    }
});

await crawler.run();
```

In options I set headless to true
When I run docker container, I get the next output:

```
Launching Puppeteer {"headless":true,"args":["--no-sandbox","--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"],"timeout":15000,"defaultViewport":{"width":1366,"height":768}}
```

Here we see that headless is true and args contains --no-sandbox

But when crawling starts, I get this error:

```
(node:66) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
[0721/143440.300775:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

The question is: why? (:

--no-sandbox is set to true, why this error even occurs?

Comment: I don't really know the answer here. Do you really need the Root user?

Comment: I suppose it will help [running puppeteer in docker](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/troubleshooting#running_puppeteer_in_docker) / [example](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/.ci/node10/Dockerfile.linux)

Answer (score 0):

You helped me quite a bit! Thank you!

So I also want to help you.

You must not execute your node.js app as root. Therefore you need to create a user and switch to that user before you execute the Docker CMD.
Add the following to your dockerfile:

```
RUN groupadd -r someuser
RUN useradd -r -g someuser -G audio,video someuser
RUN chown -R someuser:someuser /folder/of/your/app # change owner of app folder
USER someuser
CMD node index.js
```